# Determining the numerical root of a composition of a cubic map thrice with one unspecified free parameter

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

The cubic map function is

`f[x_] := (a - 1) x - a x^3`.

The function composition of the cubic map thrice is

`Expand[Nest[f, x, 3]]`.

I looked to `FindRoots` to determine the roots numerically but to no avail.

Some help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Roots[Expand[Nest[f, x, 3]]==0,x]` ??

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Is there a function that allows only the output for real roots?

Comment: Which roots are real is going to be a function of the parameter, I should think.

Comment: `Solve[Nest[f, x, 3] == 0, x, Reals] // Simplify` will provide the required conditions for the roots to be real.

Answer (score 1):

This case can be solve quite easily, though the results you get are rather complicated.
We can find, by solving a cubic, 3 values that zero the outer application of `f`.  Each of these 3 values is achieved for 3 values `f`.  Following this through, we have 27 roots.  These can be verified numerically

```
f[x_] := (a - 1) x - a x^3
Solve[f[x] == 0, x];
f[u] == x /. %;
Solve[#, u] & /@ %;
f[t] == u /. % // Flatten;
Solve[#, t] & /@ % // Flatten[#, 1] &;
Nest[f, t, 3] /. %;
% /. a -> N[73/100, 30]
(* {0, 0, 0, 0.*10^-28 + 0.*10^-28 I, 0.*10^-28 + 0.*10^-27 I, 
 0.*10^-28 + 0.*10^-27 I, 0.*10^-30 + 0.*10^-30 I, 
 0.*10^-30 + 0.*10^-30 I, 0.*10^-30 + 0.*10^-30 I, 
 0.*10^-26 + 0.*10^-26 I, 0.*10^-26 + 0.*10^-26 I, 
 0.*10^-26 + 0.*10^-26 I, 0.*10^-23 + 0.*10^-23 I, 
 0.*10^-23 + 0.*10^-23 I, 0.*10^-23 + 0.*10^-23 I, 
 0.*10^-23 + 0.*10^-23 I, 0.*10^-23 + 0.*10^-23 I, 
 0.*10^-23 + 0.*10^-23 I, 0.*10^-26 + 0.*10^-26 I, 
 0.*10^-26 + 0.*10^-26 I, 0.*10^-26 + 0.*10^-26 I, 
 0.*10^-29 + 0.*10^-28 I, 0.*10^-28 + 0.*10^-28 I, 
 0.*10^-28 + 0.*10^-28 I, 0.*10^-29 + 0.*10^-28 I, 
 0.*10^-29 + 0.*10^-28 I, 0.*10^-29 + 0.*10^-28 I} *)
```